# git workflow branches updates

Tags: git, git-merge

Here's the situation. There are 3 branches on github: master, his-tests, my-tests
Let's forget about the master branch for a moment. After the initial work on master, a person I work with created a branch 'his-tests' where he continues developing the code. I then created my branch based on his with:

```
git checkout -b my-tests
```

I have added some changes in my-tests, commited and pushed it to github. My collaborator saw the changes and implemented them in his branch (his-tests). After a few days he added more changes and I want to implement them in my branch (my-tests). How do I do it? I know I can delete my branch and clone his branch again but I can't keep doing it. What is the correct way of handling it? So when I visit github, I can see that there have been changes in his branch (1 or 2 files usually):

```
git branch -a
master
* my-branch
his-branch
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/my-branch
remotes/origin/his-branch
```

So what do I do to merge his-branch with my-branch. He has the latest state of files and I'd like all the files in my-branch be updated. As you can see I've checkout and always work in my-branch, I don't make changes in his-branch. What's the workflow of this cycle of updating my-branch with his changes and then working on it to add some changes and push my changes to my-branch on github.

Is there any more information that you need? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> So what do I do to merge his-branch with my-branch

You merge his-branch with my-branch!

First, make sure your local repo matches what you're seeing on GitHub:

```
$ git checkout his-branch
$ git pull
```

Once your local repo is up to date, you can merge the new stuff from `his-branch` into `my-branch`:

```
$ git checkout my-branch
$ git merge his-branch
```

Using `git merge` will allow git to handle any possible conflicts between the two branches. If you have conflicts but you don't care about them, and you just want your branch to be the same as his, abandoning everything else in your branch, you can move your branch with `git reset`:

```
$ git checkout my-branch
$ git reset --hard his-branch
```

Comment: **Caution:** Using `git reset --hard` will loose your changes. So do this if you want to drop/delete your own modification. (If you do it by error, there's a way to recover. But you better be carefull first)

Comment: Right: using `reset --hard` will "abandon everything else in the branch".

Comment: In this particular situation I always wait for his changes before I start working on the code so there won't be anything to discard.  Will that be ok then?

Comment: This would be ok, but that somehow defeat the purpose of using a version control system...

Comment: @Wasteland What branch are you on when you start working on the code, and what branch are the changes coming from (or stated another way, how do you get the changes)?

Comment: I see your point. So how does git handle it if I make changes to eg. one function in a code and he's done some other changes to the same piece of code? How is it merged? Whose version wins?

Comment: If modification merge well together, you'll have no trouble. If it don't, then you'll have a conflict notification that you'll have to resolve in the file (git will keep both code section marked, and you just choose which one you keep).

Comment: If exactly the same line is changed, Git will ask you to to manually resolve the conflict in some kind of editor. If you change one block in a function and he changes another block a few lines later, Git will automatically pull both changes into the file.

Comment: Ok, I understand. How can I pull his-branch so that I can merge it with my-branch?

Comment: From the other comment thread it sounds like you already pulled. If you checkout `his-branch`, do you get a message about `origin/his-branch` being ahead?

Comment: Yes, I do. See my other comment

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to merge his branch into yours:

```
git checkout my-test
git merge his-test
```

You could also `rebase` you changes onto his branch. This will keep the history straight, but you modify the history (which some people believe is bad)

```
git checkout my-test
git rebase his-test
```

If your colleague is on another remote. Start by adding the remote:

```
git remote add my-colleague-remote git@hisremote.com
```

And then, you reference the branch hold on this remote:

```
git fetch my-colleague-remote
git merge my-colleague-remote/his-branch
```

Comment: Modifying local history isn't bad; it's encouraged! Modifying history and then pushing the modification to a shared repository creates a headache for everybody else using that branch, because now *they* have to rebase to keep in sync. In this case, would rebase even work if `his-branch` is a direct descendant of `my-branch` (i.e. if there were no changes to `my-branch` after the merge of `my-branch` into `his-branch`)?

Comment: Thanks. After issuing: git merge his-test I get the message: Already up to date. This is not actually true. I then try to pull --all from my-branch but it says that I didn't specify the branch because this is not the default configured remote for my current branch. If I switch to master and pull --all it says: fetching origin, Already up-to-date.

Comment: So your colleague is on another remote?

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I don't understand the terminology. It's all based on a git repository on his github account which I initially cloned and created my branch (I have r/w access to that repo on his github account). Thanks for patience.

Comment: Try `git push -u origin my-branch` then `git pull origin his-branch`

Comment: Ok. I think we're onto something. I've done it. It has updated his-branch to the version I see in github.com. When I try to merge: git merge his-branch, it says it's up to date. When I tried to checkout to his-branch, I get the message: Your branch is behind 'origin/his-branch' by 5 commits and can be fast-forwarded.

Comment: Are you on your branch when you try to merge? (e.g.: `git checkout my-branch`)

Comment: Yes, I am on my-branch when I issue: git merge his-branch

Comment: Ok: Checkout `his-branch`, and update it from the remote: `git merge origin/his-branch`. Then checkout `my-branch`, and update it from `his-branch`: `git merge his-branch`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems to work. I need to read the whole again to remember the logic. Thank you both.